# Pass 'this' into function template, gives error

Tags: c++, function-templates

I try to pass to function template from other object the object `this` but it keep to give me compilation error. This is what my template function looks like:

in header

```
template<class T>
    void StopAndRemoveParticals(ParticleSystemQuad* &emitter,T* &parent);
```

in c++

```
template<class T> 
    void ParticleFactory::StopAndRemoveParticals(ParticleSystemQuad* &emitter,T* &parent)
    {
        bool ParticlesEmitterIsActive = emitter->isActive();
        if(emitter!= NULL)
        {        
            particaleTagName tag = (particaleTagName)emitter->getTag();
            parent->m_Parent->removeChildByTag(emitter->getTag());
        }
    }
```

calling this function from Some object :

```
1>\projects\game\classes\solutioncontainer.cpp(114): error C2664: 'void ParticleFactory::StopAndRemoveParticals<SolutionContainer>(cocos2d::ParticleSystemQuad *&,T *&)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'SolutionContainer *const ' to 'SolutionContainer *&'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=SolutionContainer
1>          ]
```

What am I doing wrong here and why can't I pass pointer to reference?

Comment: Why do you need to pass references to pointers? You're not modifying them, so you can drop the `&` from the arguments.

Comment: yeah i did try this also still gives me error:
rror LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ParticleFactory::StopAndRemoveParticals<class SolutionContainer>(class cocos2d::ParticleSystemQuad * &,class SolutionContainer *)" (??$StopAndRemoveParticals@VSolutionContainer@@@ParticleFactory@@QAEXAAPAVParticleSystemQuad@cocos2d@@PAVSolutionContainer@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall SolutionContainer::InnerCleanPreviousLevel(void)" (?InnerCleanPreviousLevel@SolutionContainer@@QAEXXZ)

Comment: Did you change both the declaration (in the header) and the definition (in the cpp file)?

Comment: @user63898: The link error is probably because you're defining the template in one source file and using it in another. You usually need to define templates in headers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021

Comment: BTW, you should avoid C-Cast.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be both an issue with const (you are probably trying to call `StopAndRemoveParticals` from another const member function), and an issue with trying to get a reference to the `this` pointer.

The code does not seem to require references to pointers, so start by removing them. Solving the const problem will require you to make modifications in the function calling `StopAndRemoveParticals`.